# Azure Mobile Services Push not working

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, push-notification

I am trying to implement push to my app.

I've followed this guide:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/

However, I am using API's instead of the Data-scripts, so in one of my API methods I am doing this:

```
   var push = request.service.push;


   push.apns.send(null, {
    alert: "Alert",
    payload: {
        inAppMessage: "Hey, a new item arrived"
    }
   }, {
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp)
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
   });
```

My log is showing this (So I land in the success-method [Also I know that I should never land in error for iOS due to apples push server not responding with error]):

```
{ isSuccessful: true,
  statusCode: 201,
  body: '',
  headers: 
   { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
     server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
     date: 'Mon, 20 Oct 2014 11:31:21 GMT' },
  md5: undefined }
```

My app is registered correctly like this, I see the callback message and no error:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: (NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [client.push registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:@[@"uniqueTag"] completion:^(NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"registerNativeWithDeviceToken callback");
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

But no push message land in my iphone! Nothing is happening.

Im trying to check for errors in my Notification Hub but I see no log there.

What am I missing? I really don't get it where my actual device id is stored server side anyway. I must be missing something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to debug what is occurring is to follow the Notification Hub debugging steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530751.aspx

I would begin by using Service Bus Explorer to double-check the registration has the device token and tags you expect. After verifying that, please test sending an alert directly via the Notification Hub portal. If you still have issues, please send me an email at toddreif@microsoft.com.

Comment: Awesome! Of course it was a credential issue. It's working now. However, my "subquestion" still stands: Where are the device id's stored? How can I for example bind the id's to a user in my database?

Comment: The following blog explains tags: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/10/22/windows-azure-notification-hubs-tags-and-creating-a-breaking-news-app.aspx We recommend the use of tags for user identification and for group identification. You can add tags either in your client or in the service.

Comment: @Spoek Sorry I missed your reply! If you are using a node Mobile Service, you can add a registration script via the portal. If you are using the .Net Mobile Services, you can add an INotificationHandler using these instructions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/08/push-notifications-using-notification-hub-and-net-backend.aspx. Without knowing the pattern of your application, I cannot say the best place to connect this data to your back-end data but I do recommend using the ZUMO InstallationID or the user token's UserID as key tags for linking rather than deviceId.

Comment: This link walks through sending a notification to a specific userId in a bit more detail: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-push-notifications-app-users/

Answer (score 0):

Use your debug menu in Azure as @Todd Reifsteck said, and please test the tag name both `"myTag"` and `myTag` while debugging.